# How to do fuzzy match with linux alias

Tags: linux, shell

I usually use "root" to login in my linux, but I want to make shell forbid my dangerous command like `fio --name=test --filename=/dev/nvme0n1`, as `/dev/nvme0n1` is my OS-drive.

So, how to configure my bashrc to make shell cmd pre-check, if command has character like `nvme0n1`, just forbid it.

I want to use alias to make it. But for now I cannot set alias in .bashrc as:

```
alias "*/dev/nvme0n1*"="do not try it!!!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment:

> I usually use "root" to login in my linux, but I want to make shell forbid dangerous commands

The best way is to simply not log in as `root` directly. Set up a regular unprivileged user account and a [`sudo` policy](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) that allows that user elevate their privileges when necessary.

Only log in with that regular user account .

That is the easiest way to greatly reduce the number of "dangerous" commands  that can successfully run and reduces risk and the amount of damage you can do to your system and the data of your other users.

Then train your self to only use `sudo` for the few occasions that you actually need to run something with root privileges.

That will help with the best remedy:

### Think before you type

---

Having said that, the default command aliases:

```
alias cp='cp -i'
alias mv='mv -i'
alias rm='rm -i'
```

that for example RHEL and possibly other OS's enable for root and the default `--preserve-root` option that GNU `rm` sets,  those do help to prevent certain (common/notorious) mishaps.

More complex and/or generic idiot proofing is difficult:

1. for starters, there is a limit to foreseeable errors (that you can successfully recognise and catch).
2. there is an unlimited potential for costly mistakes and typo's.
3. your *"dangerous"* might actually be what ***I*** want and need to do.

---

## Possible approach

Zsh has the `precmd` and `preexec` hooks (and that functionality appears to be ported to bash in some form [here](https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec)) which can be used to **evaluate each command before execution**.

You can use that to:

- do string matching for your "dangerous options"  list before running/rejecting the command
- present a (conditional) confirmation prompt when certain criteria match as seen in the example here: https://reespozzi.medium.com/cancel-a-terminal-command-during-preexec-zsh-function-c5b0d27b99fb#86cb

  ```
    # Sanity Checks
    preexec () { 
    if [[ ${CLUSTER} =~ "prod" || ${CLUSTER} =~ "production" ]];then
       if [[ ${1} =~ "delete" || ${1} =~ "edit" || ${1} =~ "uninstall" ]];then
       read -q "execStatus?-----  DETECTED PROD CONTEXT: Definitely execute command? [y/n]  ----- "
      if [[ ${execStatus} == "y" ]];then
         printf "\nExecuting...\n"
       else
         printf "\nCancelled $1... Refreshing shell."
         exec zsh
       fi
      else
        echo "Successfully parsed for: [delete, edit, uninstall], executing command in prod context..."
      fi
    fi
  }
  ```

Adjust to your own needs.

Note that a problem with too frequent confirmation prompts is that human behaviour will start seeing them as routine, people will stop reading them carefully  and simply confirm, defeating their purpose.